# Need help concerning zipcode tables join statement

Tags: php, mysql, join, select, zipcode

Very new to coding. I have 2 tables, zips_usa which includes all properly formatted zips (zipcode, lat / lon / city / state etc) in the US, and table ageus which includes columns such as first name, last name, category, comments. It took 3 weeks to write the zipcode radius search but I got there, mainly due to answers I found on this site. Thanks.
I now need help dealing with the output. I think I need a join statement between the tables and cannot get my head around the logic. Any help would be appreciated.

sql statement for zip radius search runs error free. Input is performed by a html form.

```
  $sql = "SELECT latitude, longitude FROM zips_usa WHERE zipcode = '$zipcode'";
```

Table ageus column details (where users post to)

id first_name last_name dog_type comments city state entered gender category zipcode

How do I join the two tables so I can select output that includes all info from table ageus that includes zip codes found within the X mile radius?

Comment: Your code is **wide open** to SQL injection attacks.  Don't insert variables into your query like this.  Instead, use a parameterized query.

Comment: Try inner join query

Comment: @Brad How do you know this?  If a zipcode comes from a submitted value, all that is necessary is something like $zipcode = intval($POST['zipcode']);  But that is not shown here.  You do not know, in this case, where $zipcode came from. Did you know you are very unlikely to  be subjected to SQL Injection (sqli)?  That is unless your knowledge of sqli comes from the jackals selling sqli solutions.  I get my information on security from NIST.  NIST never mentions sqli in their recommendations for securing websites.  There are so many other easier  vulnerabilities   to exploit than sqli.

Comment: @Misunderstood Lol, any time you insert arbitrary data into a different context, it needs to be treated properly.  In this case, that means escaping data properly.  Sure, there's no integer that gets executed as SQL, and that'd be safe, but did you read the question?  "Very new to coding", it says.  All queries with arbitrary data should be parameterized.  Then, there's nothing to worry about.  Otherwise... somebody somewhere may change that variable to something you don't expect, and you'll have a bad day.  Learn to do it right... it takes no extra effort.

Comment: You lost me at LOL. I agree, you should learn.  i.e. Parameterization is not a panacea for sqli.  Although intval($zipcode) is a surefire solution.   "Nothing to worry about", that is  so NOT true.   Do it right. My point is you are not right.  I do HIPPA compliant web apps.  If I make a mistake it will cost me $50,000 plus.  And you?  It appears to me you get your information from the jackals selling their so called "sqli solutions".  And yes I did read the question.  And your comment was no help.  The worst part is you do not understand sqli.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks again to everyone who answered. Using Misunderstood's suggestions to populate the fields, I was able to get the script fully working by using the "Populating a table from query results (mysql)" thread, from 13 years ago, amending the details accordingly to mysqli. I've only been coding since I retired a few months ago. This is a fantastic site for learning all this new stuff. More importantly, we now have a working dog / animal rescue site YAY.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is a table with a zipcode, lat, lng, a radius to find every record in the table that is within that radius,  and a list of the lat and lng for each zipcode.

I made a "ziplocation" table.

```
$sql = "SELECT `lat`,`lng` FROM `zipLocation` WHERE `zip` = $zip ";
$results = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
list($lat,$lng) = mysqli_fetch_array($results, MYSQLI_NUM);
```

The use the results to populate the table with lat and lng in addition to the zipcode.

The best approach, IMHO, is to use the list of zipcode lat and lng to put populate the table's lat and long.

A table of zips with lat and lang is easy to find. 
Here is the query:

```
$sql = "SELECT `level`,`id`,`pics`,`name`,`city`,`zip` , ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians($lat) ) * cos( radians( `lat` ) ) * cos( radians( `lng` ) - radians($lng) ) + sin( radians($lat) ) * sin( radians( `lat` ) ) ) ) AS `distance` FROM `photos` WHERE 1 HAVING `distance` <= $miles ORDER BY `distance` ASC";
```

I copied the above sql from a demo app I did for a client in Ft. Lauderdale wanting an dating site.
The user enters their zipcode and a radius and  it shows the available girls within that radius.

The number at the bottom of the page is the number of seconds it took to generate the HTML.

[Dating app where only Girls within a zipcode radius are shown](http://eatled.com/show.php)

Comment: Many thanks for the advice, info and updates folks, appreciate it. I'm aware I need to improve my overall coding knowledge and I'm working on that. My zipcode radius search returns all the values I'd expect and they're very accurate distance wise. I already have a script that can process one zipcode and my aim is to pass the output of the radius script to it so a user can increase the search distance from whatever zipcode they live in and I'm still not sure how to pass those results to it or indeed if there's another way. Spent two days attempting inner joins with no luck :-(